# Method chaining and returning value from method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, chaining

this is a general question about Python class method chaining. I have a class that performs some data wrangling operations and returns a dataframe for the methods. I'm trying to method chain using the methods after creating the dataframe object, much like Pandas does. However, I seem to be running into some issues. Here's a simple example of a couple of methods in the class:

```
class Data:

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def remove_rows(self, col):
        df = (perform_some_operations)
        return df

    def collapse(self, cols):
        df = (perform_some_operations)
        return df
```

So I can use this like so:

```
df = Data(df)
df = df.remove_rows(col_1)
df = df.collapse(col_1)
```

However, if I want to use it like:

```
df = df.remove_rows(col_1).collapse(col_1)
```

I will get errors. Now if I returned `self` from these methods, I am able to chain them together, but the output is the `Data` object instead of a dataframe.

In `Pandas`, you are able to, for example do the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df = df.rename(columns={'col_1':'COL_1'}).drop(columns=['COL_1'])
```

and also

```
df = df.rename(columns={'col_1':'COL_1'})
df = df.drop(columns=['COL_1'])
```

I would like to understand how I can create methods that allow me to both chain operations but also use them separately to get values if I need to. I did some research and it seems like you can do one or the other, but if you take `Pandas` for example, you are able to do both.

Comment: No, in `pandas` you can only do one... it returns self ... a `pd.DataFrame`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to use self.df in methods
Like this:

```
class Data:

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def remove_rows(self, col):
        self.df = (perform_some_operations)
        return self.df

    def collapse(self, cols):
        self.df = (perform_some_operations)
        return self.df
```

Comment: this fails since I can't chain on the Dataframe value returned